# Bash: Can I evaluate a format string for numbers in a non-constant range without using "eval"?

Tags: bash, range, interpolation

I am not happy having to use eval, but everything else I tried failed because of limits on the `{a..b}` syntax.  Here's what I have, and yes
I know I could combine the two loops, but the eval's ugly enough already.

```
cores=""
suffixes=""
np=$(nproc --all)
eval 'for i in {1..'$np'} ; do cores="$cores $i"; done'
for i in $cores ; do
  suffixes="$suffixes "$(printf %02i $i)
done
```

Comment: `for ((i=0; i<np; i++)); do ...`

Comment: `suffixes="$(printf '%02i ' $(seq $(nproc --all) ) )"`

Comment: @twalberg, ...if we were willing to require on a non-POSIX tool that doesn't ship with bash, such as `seq`. Eww.

Comment: Hmmm.... wasn't aware that `seq` was non-POSIX... Ah, well...

Comment: Incidentally, the [`counting` factoid](http://wooledge.org/~greybot/meta/counting) in Greybot, the factoid bot in the irc.freenode.org #bash channel, provides mechanisms to efficiently and idiomatically iterate over numeric ranges in several different shells.

Comment: BTW -- what's the actual use case here? "suffixes" sounds like a collection, but if you want to have something iterable, the ideal data structure would probably be an array rather than a string with a bunch of whitespace-separated numbers. In that case, my answer would be: `suffixes=( ); for ((i=0; i<np; i++)); do printf -v suffix '%02i' "$i"; suffixes+=( "$i" ); done`, and iterating over them would look like: `for suffix in "${suffixes[@]}"; do : something_with "$suffix"; done`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy The use case is creating queues of work, and files of results for a highly-parallelizable problem.  I'll be doing this for a few years I think.  Even without all the cores I recently got, I've generated over 90 million results so far.  And the overall use case is exploration of a strategy game.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, an aggressively modern solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
#      ^^^^- "printf -v" and C-style for loops both require bash, not /bin/sh

np=$(nproc --all)
cores=( )
for ((i=0; i<np; i++)); do
  printf -v suffix '%02i' "$i"
  cores[$i]=$suffix
done
```

This generates a single indexed array: Its keys are the core numbers, and its values are the suffix strings. Thus, you can iterate over `"${!cores[@]}"` to get a list of core numbers; over `"${cores[@]}"` to get a list of suffix strings, or use `"${cores[$i]}"` to look up the suffix for core `$i`.

---

Next, a solution closer to the original code, built for modern bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
#      ^^^^- "printf -v" and C-style for loops both require bash, not /bin/sh

np=$(nproc --all)
cores=""; suffixes=""
for ((i=0; i<np; i++)); do
  printf -v suffix '%02i' "$i"
  cores+=" $i"
  suffixes+=" $suffix"
done
```

You could also build only the core numbers inside the array, and calculate the suffix numbers in one step:

```
# read cores from string into an array to allow safe evaluation even with unknown IFS
IFS=' ' read -r -a cores_arr <<<"$cores"
# ...and expand the full array, repeating the format string for every element
printf -v suffixes '%02i ' "${cores_arr[@]}"
```

Notably:

- Iterating over an expanded array, ie. `for i in $cores`, is generally bad practice -- if your values are *guaranteed* to only be numeric it can be safe, but to be aware of the side effects:

  - Glob expressions inside the string are expanded: If you somehow had a `*` in your data, you'd find yourself iterating over files in the current directory.
  - String-splitting does not allow the fine-grained control over element boundaries that arrays do. You can have `array=( "item one" "item two" )` to store two items, with spaces in both their names; if you tried setting `string=' "item one" "item two" '`, you'd get `"item` as one word, `one"` as a second word, etc.

  Consequently, iterating over array elements -- even if this means reading from a string *into* an array -- is strongly preferred.
- Looping over an arbitrary number of items is best done with a [C-style `for` loop](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/c_for).
- In the above, there are no external commands other than `nproc`. This means we aren't depending on non-POSIX tools such as `seq`.
- Using `printf -v suffix` writes the result of the string-formatting operations performed by `printf` directly to the variable named `suffix`. (Aside: ksh93 does not have `printf -v`, but recognizes use of printf inside `$()` and avoids the subshell penalty). See [the bash-hackers page on `printf`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/printf).
- Consequently: There are no subshells other than that needed to run said external command and capture its output. (Each subshell requires `fork()`ing off another copy of the shell after using `mkfifo()` to generate a FIFO to capture its output; reading that output; `wait()`ing for the subshell to exit, etc; as such, they're best kept outside of tight loops).

---

If you needed compatibility with POSIX sh, by contrast, then we still have `$(( ))` but not `(( ))` (and no `+=` operation except in a math context, and no C-style `for` loops at all). This leaves us with:

```
#!/bin/sh
build_suffix() {
  np=$1; i=0
  while [ "$i" -lt "$np" ]; do
    printf '%02i ' "$i"
    i=$((i+1))
  done
}
suffixes=$(build_suffix "$(nproc --all)")
```

...which gives us an answer with exactly two subshells, no matter how many times we loop, by putting the entire loop inside of a single subshell.

Comment: Thank you Charles, this gives me all the ideas I need.  I was enamored of the {1..n} syntax that I had just discovered, and in spite of having been writing shell stuff for a decade or so, had never needed or used the C-style for (( ))

Answer (score 1):

```
suffixes=''
np="$(nproc --all)"
for ((i=0; i <$np; ++i)); do suffixes="$suffixes $(printf %02i $i)"; done
```

Comment: `suffixes+=` is both shorter and more efficient.

Comment: though, really, if we cared about efficiency, we'd ditch the subshell -- `$()` is expensive.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: We are speaking of enumerating CPU cores. The nice `printf` makes all suffixes the same length.

Comment: "The same length"? What does that have to do with anything? When I said "shorter", I meant shorter to write, in terms of your code.

Comment: ...and I don't mean to tell you to get rid of printf, I mean to tell you not to use it in a subshell.

Comment: It happens I want all the suffixes to be the same length, and that's what my existing code does.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the input, everyone.  It's given me a few things to think about.  I've settled on this to replace the for-loop and call to printf(1):

```
np=$(nproc --all)
suffixes=$(eval "echo {01..$np}")
```

It's succinct, and the quoting is obvious.  I'm still not thrilled with eval, but it's not using untrusted data, and it contributes very (very!) little runtime in the overall scheme of what I'm doing.